# Is there a standard for English print writing?

Tags: handwriting

I want to know the 'correct' or 'standard' way to write print if there is one.

For example;
hook vs loop in lowercase g,
hook vs loop vs straight line in lowercase q,
horizontal bar vs no bar in uppercase J,
etc.

Comment: no there is no one correct or standard way to print the English alphabet

Comment: @green_ideas: that is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: go ahead and post it as an answer... but I imagined it can be expanded

Comment: Mostly the differences exist for hysterical reasons.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about handwriting not language.

Comment: then "why the h3ll" is there a handwriting tag with handwriting questions

Comment: @green_ideas - Doesn't the system let you make up tags as you go? (Having said that, I think this is not an unreasonable question.)

Comment: @nnnnnn the handwriting tag has been around for some years; besides, isn't there a minimum rep for tag creation?

Comment: Just because the answer is "no" doesn't make the question unreasonable. In many other languages a qualified "yes" could be given, in that one letter form is consistently taught and this persists into adult use

Comment: @HotLicks - You're saying people change their handwriting when they get upset?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there are two acceptable ways to print lowercase letters, depending on where you look.[1][2][3]

[Wikipedia][1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet
[ASCII] [2]: http://www.asciitable.com/
[Video] [3]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=piiZi5S9nKo

Comment: Do you think many organisations have style guides that cover this sort of detail for *handwriting*?

Comment: If you can point to an example of a handwriting style guide, I'll change my down vote to an up vote - that would actually answer the question. There are standards for technical lettering, but that's not handwriting in the usual sense

Comment: Oh, is that what "write print" means?  My mistake.  I've never heard "write print" for "print" before.  Any old school English textbook shows you how to print standard English letters. [1] [2]

[Literacy Center][1] https://www.literacycenter.net/print_practice/print-english-lowercase-letters.php

[English Club] [2] https://www.englishclub.com/writing/alphabet.htm